# Simple audio player with playlist not working on IE,Safari and Opera?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to play music from playlist. I do like this

**Simple Player**

```
<audio id="audio" preload="auto" tabindex="0" controls="" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source type="audio/mp3" src="music/demo.mp3">
    Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
</audio>
```

**Playlist**

```
<ul id="playlist">
  <?php if($lists) { foreach ($lists as $key=> $list) { ?>
    <li class="active">
      <a src="music/<?php  echo $list;  ?>.mp3">
         <?php  echo $list;  ?> </a>
    </li>   
  <?php }}?>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var audio;
var playlist;
var tracks;
var current;

init();
function init(){
    current = 0;
    audio = $('audio');
    playlist = $('#playlist');
    tracks = playlist.find('li a');
    len = tracks.length - 1;

    playlist.find('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        link = $(this);
        current = link.parent().index();
        run(link, audio[0]);
    });
    audio[0].addEventListener('ended',function(e){

        if(current == len){
            current = 0;
            link = playlist.find('a')[0];
        }else{
         current++;
            link = playlist.find('a')[current];    

        run($(link),audio[0]);
        }

    });
}
function run(link, player){
        player.src = link.attr('src');
        par = link.parent();
        par.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        audio[0].load();
        audio[0].play(); }
```

Unfortunately playlist click event only working on firefox and chrome but not to IE,Safari and Opera. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `href` instead of `src` for the `<a>` tags?